# Taylor's inequality question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Totally don't know how to go about doing this. Any help/insight would be appreciated.

Comment: It could be that I'm over thinking this...

Comment: Did you try, using the Taylor series for $f(x)=e^x$?

Comment: Expand using Taylor polynomials. Apply your version of Taylor's theorem. Conclude the answer. This is a question designed to test your comprehension, so it's good for you to spend the time to really understand it.

Comment: I'm still confused. I looked up the taylor expansion of $e^x$ but I don't get what to do with it given the interval. I haven't done any calculus in a long time and I'm very rusty.

Answer (score 1):

They just want you to use Taylor-Lagrange inequality :
$$\forall x \in I, \left|f(x)-g(x)\right| \leq M \frac{\left|x\right|^{5}}{5!}$$

Where $M=e^{10}$ is I guess sufficient. (Notice how the RHS is a monomial with $a = \frac{e^{10}}{120} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k=5\geq0$)